# Install Teams on RDP

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams, remote-desktop

I want to install Teams on RDP server 2012 R2. How should I do it?
Is there any special requirement or should I just go Microsoft websie and install desktop app as a administrator. All the users will be using it. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/microsoft-365/microsoft-teams/download-app

Comment: It really really doesn’t work well on rdp

Comment: The client wants to use it for Chatting and Channels only

Comment: Use the web version - we tried deploying rd session hosts with teams and it does not work well